# Flask: The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application

Tags: python-3.x, flask

```
basic-flask-app.config:

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 10.13.18.150
    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/basic-flask-app/app.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/basic-flask-app>
            WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/basic-flask-app/static
    <Directory /var/www/basic-flask-app/static/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/www/basic-flask-app/logs/error.logs
    CustomLog /var/www/basic-flask-app/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

app.wsgi:
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/basic-flask-app/')
activate_this = '/var/www/basic-flask-app/venv/bin/activate_this.py'

with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(),dict(__file__ = activate_this))

from app import app as application

app.py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect,session
from spotipy import Spotify
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth, SpotifyClientCredentials
# import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)

# @app.route('/')
# def index():
#     return render_template('index.html')


# db = mysql.connector.connect(
#     host="localhost",
#     user="root",
#     password="xxxxxxxxx",
#     database="spotify"
# )

SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:3000'

sp_oauth = SpotifyOAuth(client_id=SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID,client_secret=SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET,redirect_uri=SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    auth_url = sp_oauth.get_authorize_url()
    print(auth_url)
    return redirect(auth_url)


@app.route('/search_tracks')
def search_tracks(limit=20):
    token_info = sp_oauth.get_access_token()
    access_token = token_info['access_token']
    sp = Spotify(auth=access_token)
    search_tracks = request.args.get('search_tracks')
    print(search_tracks)
    results = sp.search(q=search_tracks, type='track', limit=limit)
    if 'tracks' in results:
        tracks = results['tracks']['items']
        if tracks:
            print(f"First {limit} results for '{search_tracks}':")
            songs = []
            for index, track in enumerate(tracks, start=1):
                song = {
                    'name': track['name'],
                    'artist': track['artists'][0]['name'],
                    'uri': track['uri'],
                    'song_source' : track['artists'][0]['external_urls']["spotify"],
                    'artists_id' : track['artists'][0]['id']
                }
                songs.append(song)
            return render_template('results.html', songs=songs)

        else:
            print(f"No results found for '{search_tracks}'")
    else:
        print(f"Error in the search results for '{search_tracks}'")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

In flask the first page is coming correctly but when I click and redirect it takes time and shows gateway timeout. In error logs its showing """Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'flaskapp': /var/www/basic-flask-app/app.wsgi, referer: [http://10.13.18.150/"""](http://10.13.18.150/%22%22%22). I dont know what to do. The page is not redirecting. I have given apache config TimeOut 600. Still not working. Is there any solution for this.